# How to make a local dependency depend on a feature in Cargo?

Tags: dependencies, rust, rust-cargo

Given this small library which uses local crates in subdirectories, how would I make one of the dependencies optional, depending on if a feature is enabled?

```
[package]
name = "image_load"
description = "Small wrapper for image reading API's."
version = "0.1.0"

[features]

default = ["use_png"]

[dependencies]

[dependencies.image_load_ppm]
path = "ppm"

# How to make this build _only_ when 'use_png' feature is enabled?
[dependencies.image_load_png]
path = "png"
```

While I read [the documentation](http://doc.crates.io/manifest.html#the-features-section), this shows how to have optional *external* dependencies. In the example above I'm using a local subdirectory, which I want to build, or not - based on a feature.

How can I make `image_load_png` only build when the `use_png` feature is enabled.

Comment: You can check out the [documentation](http://doc.crates.io/manifest.html#the-features-section) for it.

Comment: I read this page, but didn't see examples of this.

Comment: It's under the comment **# A list of all of the optional dependencies**.

Comment: @Shepmaster, yes, I read this. The difference is my dependency is local, instead of an optional external crate, the difference in syntax threw me. Updated the question to make this clear.

Answer (score 6):

This can be done by adding the following:

```
[package]
name = "image_load"
version = "0.1.0"
description = "Small wrapper for image reading API's."

[features]

default = ["use_png"]
use_png = ["image_load_png"]  # <-- new line

[dependencies]

[dependencies.image_load_ppm]
path = "ppm"

[dependencies.image_load_png]
path = "png"
optional = true  # <-- new line
```

Using the crate can be optional.

e.g.:

```
#[cfg(feature = "use_png")]  // <-- new line
extern crate image_load_png;
```

Answer (score 1):

Dependencies marked as optional double as features. However, if you want a feature with a different name, you'll have to [define it manually](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39736576/234590).

For instance, if you mark the dependency `image_load_png` as optional, then `image_load_png` will only be compiled if the `image_load_png` feature is enabled. You can test for the feature being enabled in the Rust code just like any other feature.

```
[dependencies.image_load_png]
path = "png"
optional = true
```